# Whenever I run this code it says File Not found, despite me being positive it exists

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import sklearn

from numpy.f2py.tests import test_size

from sklearn import linear_model

from sklearn.utils import shuffle

data = pd.read_csv("student-mat.csv", sep=";")
```

My code is a bit longer than this, but this is the important part, whenever I run it, it comes out with an error I haven't been able to fix. I am positive the file exists.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File student-mat.csv does not exist: 'student-mat.csv'
```

Comment: Have you checked the file location?

Comment: *Where* does the file exist?  Having a file of that name somewhere on your hard drive does you no good, it has to be in the current working directory (which is likely to be the same directory containing your script, but this depends on how exactly you ran the script).  Or you can give a full pathname to the file, wherever it actually is.

Comment: How do you run this script, the command line, an IDE, clicking on the desktop? Add `import os;print(os.getcwd())` - is the current directory the one with the file?

Comment: post has been answered, thank you guys

Comment: If its the answer given, please accept it so we know it is resolved.

Comment: uhh idk how to do that i just started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the full path - e.g. if the file is in 'c:\myfiles' use:

```
    data = pd.read_csv(r"c:\myfiles\student-mat.csv", sep=";")
```